# Installing KDE desktop in ubuntu 16.04 error

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, dpkg, kde

I'm trying to install KDE in my ubuntu 16.04 but when it was almost done, the terminal displayed me these error:

> Errors were encountered while processing: 
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/kaccounts-providers_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem and according to 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/+bug/1451728

This file overlaps with a file in gnome's account-plugin-facebook
  /usr/share/accounts/services/facebook-im.service

and kaccounts-providers has a file which overlaps with gnome's account-    plugin-google
  /usr/share/accounts/providers/google.provider

gnome and kde need to be co-installable so these files should be renamed  to not overlap.

So, this is a bug and has to be resolved by the ubuntu and kde fellas.
A workaround is to try the following:

```
sudo dpkg -r  account-plugin-google unity-scope-gdrive
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I just tried it.

Comment: I received above mentioned error by running `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` after installing Ubuntu 16.04 on a 7 year old Dell Inspiron 530 with an SSD, your two commands removed the error.

Comment: This helped me to install kubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu 18.04:

`sudo dpkg -r friends-twitter account-plugin-twitter friends-facebook account-plugin-facebook`

Comment: @AlexeyFrishman your comment helped me as well